# echo command works when manually executed but not when inserted as bash script

Tags: bash, sound, hdmi

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 and I have sound crackling over HDMI using AMD RX460 connected to my LG LED TV.

This probably has something to do with AMD GPU driver because I have the exact same problem on Windows 10 pro. On windows I have used AMD Adrenaline GUI to fix the problem by not letting the GPU go into p-State 0 (214 MHz, 0.8v). There I set the p-State 1 as minimum state and modified the frequency and voltage to match the p-State 0 ones. Probably p-State 0 apply some other power saving setting which is why setting the same frequency and voltage for p-state 1 does produce the same crackling in sound.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing on Ubuntu 19.04 but with amdgpu driver.
I have created to files hdmi-audio-crack-fix and hdmi-audio-crack-fix.service as follow:

1- Placed hdmi-audio-crack-fix inside /usr/bin with proper permissions.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This simple script disables pstate 0 for amdgpu to fix audio crackling over hdmi.
# Then pstate 1 is modified to match pstate 0 voltage and frequency.
# Also a little bit of undervolting is introduced.
# Copy to /usr/bin/ and then copy .service file to /etc/systemd/system/

# Using Ubuntu echo located inside /bin instead of bash built-in echo
amdgpu_echo="/bin/echo"

# Change amdgpu dpm performance level to manual
$amdgpu_echo "manual" > /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/power_dpm_force_performance_level

# Disable pstate 0 as this is causing the crackling over hdmi
$amdgpu_echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7" >  /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/pp_dpm_sclk
$amdgpu_echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7" >  /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_dpm_sclk

# Now reduce pstate 1 clock to reduce temperature on idle
$amdgpu_echo "s 1 220 800" > /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/pp_od_clk_voltage

# Undervolting gpu for highest pstates
$amdgpu_echo "s 5 1138 992" > /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/pp_od_clk_voltage
$amdgpu_echo "s 6 1172 1005" > /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/pp_od_clk_voltage
$amdgpu_echo "s 7 1212 1050" > /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/pp_od_clk_voltage
# Now sync new core/voltage table with GPU
$amdgpu_echo 'c' > /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/pp_od_clk_voltage
```

2- Placed hdmi-audio-crack-fix.service inside /etc/systemd/system/ and executed `sudo systemctl enable hdmi-audio-crack-fix.service`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Temporary fix for amdgpu HDMI audio crackling

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/hdmi-audio-crack-fix

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Everything works as expected but the following line doesn't seem to have any effects and the GPU still goes to p-State 0:

```
$amdgpu_echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7" >  /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/pp_dpm_sclk
```

or

```
$amdgpu_echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7" >  /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_dpm_sclk
```

The problem is when I execute this command manually through terminal using the following command it works properly:

```
sudo su -
echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7" >  /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_dpm_sclk
```

**Update:**

This is the Output of service status:

```
● hdmi-audio-crack-fix.service - Temporarly fix for amdgpu HDMI audio crackling
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/hdmi-audio-crack-fix.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2019-05-04 21:24:25 +0430; 4h 14min ago
 Main PID: 1004 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 04 21:24:24 Rivendell systemd[1]: Starting Temporarly fix for amdgpu HDMI audio crackling...
May 04 21:24:25 Rivendell systemd[1]: hdmi-audio-crack-fix.service: Succeeded.
May 04 21:24:25 Rivendell systemd[1]: Started Temporarly fix for amdgpu HDMI audio crackling.
```

Comment: Does `systemctl status hdmi-audio-crack-fix.service` show any errors?

Comment: I have edited the main post and added the output of the `systemctl status hdmi-audio-crack-fix.service`

Comment: If you call the script from terminal do the amdgpu echos work?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix well it works, except for that specific line that I have mentioned above. That command only works when I use `sudo su -` first.

Comment: Yes you need `sudo` powers to write to system directories. `sudo scriptname` is easier.

Comment: What's wrong with using regular `echo` in bash?

Comment: well I though that if echo works in terminal, then maybe the problem is with bash built-in echo command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found the problem, it had nothing to do with bash script.
The command that I said was not able to produce the desired behavior of the gpu was actually working.

What I didn't know was that whenever pp_od_clk_voltage gets modified, pp_dpm_sclk resets to default. Thus making any changes prior to modifying pp_od_clk_voltage useless.

I just needed to excute the commands related to pp_dpm_sclk after the commands related to pp_od_clk_voltage. The final working script is as follow if anyone is interested(AMD RX460):

```
#!/bin/bash
# **************************************Info************************************* #
#                                         #
# This simple script disables p-State 0 for amdgpu: fix audio-crackling over hdmi.#
# Then p-State 1 is modified to match p-State 0 voltage and frequency.        #
# Also a little bit of undervolting is also introduced to keep gpu happy.     #
#                                         #
# *************************************README************************************ #
#                                         #
# Inside the directory containing hdmi-audio-crack-fix and .service files, run:   #
#                                         #
#   sudo cp hdmi-audio-crack-fix /usr/bin/                    #
#       sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/hdmi-audio-crack-fix                  #
#   sudo cp hdmi-audio-crack-fix.service /etc/systemd/system/         #
#   sudo systemctl enable hdmi-audio-crack-fix.service            #
#                                         #
# Check if everything is working as intended:                     #
#       cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_od_clk_voltage             #
#       cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_dpm_sclk           #
#                                         #
# **************************************END************************************** #

# Change amdgpu dpm performance level to manual
echo "manual" > /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/power_dpm_force_performance_level

# Reduceing p-State 1 and 2 clock to reduce temperature on idle
echo "s 1 220 800" > /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo "s 2 620 810" > /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/pp_od_clk_voltage

# Undervolting gpu for the highest p-States: 5, 6, 7
echo "s 5 1138 992" > /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo "s 6 1172 1005" > /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo "s 7 1212 1050" > /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/pp_od_clk_voltage

# Now sync new core/voltage table with GPU
echo "c" > /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/pp_od_clk_voltage

# Finally, Disable pstate 0 as this is causing the crackling over hdmi
# This step should run after any modification to pp_od_clk_voltage, otherwise it gets reset.
echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7" >  /sys/devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.0/pp_dpm_sclk
```